# mysql join query with many fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have following tables in mysql.

focus

```
focus_id focus
1        Company
2        Name
```

events_focus

```
id  event_id    focus_id
1   1           2
2   1           1
3   2           1
```

events

```
event_id name 
1        event
2        evemt2
```

story

```
story_id name
2        storyname
3        testname
```

events_story

```
id event_id story_id
2           2
```

and this is my query

```
SELECT `focus`.`focus_id`, `focus`.`focus`, `events`.`event_id`, `events`.`name`, `story`.`story_id`, `story`.`name` 
FROM (`focus`) 
JOIN `events_focus` ON `events_focus`.`focus_id` = `focus`.`focus_id` 
JOIN `events` ON `events`.`event_id` = `events_focus`.`event_id` 
JOIN `events_story` ON `events_story`.`event_id` = `events`.`event_id` 
JOIN `story` ON `story`.`story_id` = `events_story`.`story_id` 
WHERE `focus`.`focus` = 'Company'
```

but I am getting zero result for this.

can anyone help me how to get all this data related to the tables I have shown.

Comment: Your event story table values doesn't looks right. Either event_id is null or story_id is null? Am assuming id is PK and hence with value 2 and that could be the reason for empty result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event_id` blank in the single row present in `events_story`
so the following join does not work,

```
JOIN `events_story` ON `events_story`.`event_id` = `events`.`event_id`
```

If this data is expected/valid, you might want to change the join from `JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. You'll find out which table returns `NULL` values, i.e. will provoke 0 results when using just `JOIN`